# How does javers handle situation like entity module rename and package rename

Tags: javers

See following code, for some reason, I need to rename java package name from me.prince to com.prince, and change name to personName. How does javers track the changes in this case?

```
package me.prince;
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;
    String description;

    public Person(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@TypeName` annotation for Entities, it gives you freedom of class names refactoring.

see https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#mapping-configuration